# current user is always is administrator on a SharePoint App

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, 2013, sharepoint-addin

I have tried following solution to check the current user's permissions on the current host web in a SharePoint hosted app, however the user is always administrator.

```
function sharePointReady() {
     hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
     appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));

     context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      hostWebContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);

     currentWeb = hostWebContext.get_web();
     user = hostWebContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
     context.load(user);
     context.load(currentWeb, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');

      context.executeQueryAsync(onAppReadySuccess, onAppReadyFailed);
}

function onAppReadySuccess() {

     alert(currentWeb.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has(SP.PermissionKind.fullMask));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some additional details? What permissions does the user actually have? Even if the user does not have permissions he is shown having the full mask permissions?

Comment: Now when I have tested and logged in to my dev machine as Another user the code returned right person. the problem is when you use /_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true to log in as Another user then the user is Always that user that has loged on into the machine

Comment: That's probably because you have to close the current browser session and open a new one before you login as another user.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function onAppReadySuccess() {
   var isSiteAdmin = currentUser.get_isSiteAdmin();
   if (isSiteAdmin == true)
     console.alert('I am an administrator');
   }
}
```